# Button is not get clicked

Tags: python, selenium

The script needs to click button "Ok" which is located on the pop-up. The button is not surrounded by any IFrame, only Textarea is inside IFrame. I used CSS Selector and XPath to click a button and it's not get clicked and no error is reproduced.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mceu_7']").click()   
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@src='https://qsm.qoo10.sg/gmkt.inc.gsm.web/common/scripts/module/tiny_mce_4.5.7/source/plugins/codemirror/source.html']"))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/textarea").send_keys("Some text")
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# Click on the "Ok" button.
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#mceu_108 > button:nth-child(1)").click()
```

As well button was clicked before using `switch_to.default_content()`.
This is how Pop-up looks:
[image]

Can you please help me what might be the issue?

HTML code:

```
<div id="mceu_107-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" >
<div id="mceu_107-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div>
<div id="mceu_108" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-primary mce-abs-layout-item mce-first mce-btn-has-text" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_108" role="button">
<button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1" >
<span class="mce-txt">Ok</span></button></div><div id="mceu_109" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-abs-layout-item mce-last mce-btn-has-text" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_109" role="button">
<button role="presentation" type="button"><span class="mce-txt">Cancel</span></button></div></div>
```

Comment: Could you provide HTML code?

Comment: `@id` value might be dynamic. Did you try another selector, e.g. XPath `//*[.="Ok"]`?

Comment: Updated with the HTML code

Comment: That's not enough. Please provide a HTML block to see where is your button, not just button itself

Comment: oh sorry, i added more html code

Comment: Why as external link, why not just paste in question?

Comment: pasted code into a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things :

1. You are using `find_elements_by_css_selector` instead of `find_element_by_css_selector`.
   Note that **find_elements** would return a list of web element.
2. The **Ok** text is between the **span tag**, so using `//span[text()='Ok']` might not work.The **parent tag** of this **span** is a **button**, So clicking on a **button** much sense than clicking on **span**.

**Code** you can try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Ok']/parent::button").click()
```

Since you have mentioned that, it is not present in **iframe**. This code should work for you.

Hope that will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! that worked well, but why it didn't work when i used css_selector or xpath with   `find_element_by`  on the button element?

Comment: You have used this code `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#mceu_108 > button:nth-child(1)").click()` , when you use `find_elements` then you will have list of web element and invoking click on list is not applicable.

Comment: Second reason could be your locators , clicking on button is much logical than clicking on span , hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If it's a popup maybe you have to wait for the button until it appears, 
take a look at this http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.
wish it helps!

Comment: i have delay before click and before pop-up is appearing on the screen